# GWT Methods setVisible and removeFromParent

Tags: gwt

Is `UIObject#setVisible(false)` functionally different from `Widget#removeFromParent`?

Besides, Is `DialogBox#hide` just a wapper call to `UIObject#setVisible(false)`?

Any practical examples?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`UIObject#setVisible` sets the CSS 'display' attribute on the element. If you have an `HTMLPanel` and call setVisible(false) on it, it will result in this

> < div style="display:none">My HTML Panel !< /div>

Whereas removeFromParent will remove the element from the DOM of your page. Again, if you had an `HTMLPanel` attached to the body of your page and called removeFromParent() on it, you would go from

```
< body>
    <div >My HTML Panel !</div>
</body>
```

to

```
< body> < /body>
```

So once you've remove a widget from it's parent, you will have to reattach it if you want to display it again.

As for your second question, I haven't looked at the code for `DialogBox#hide` but I would say that it probably calls `setVisible(false)` at some point, among other things.

Comment: The end result is : the user won't see them anymore. So no. But if you use setVisible(false), the element is still in the page. Someone who knows how to use firebug or Chrome's console or whatever other plugin can change the style of the element and set it visible again.

Answer (score 0):

I found useful application of setVisible() method in hiding nested presenters. If you want to remove nested presenter from one of your pages, in your onReset() method you could do something like:

```
    if(mainPagePresenter.isVisible()){getView().getMenuBar().setVisible(false);}
    else{getView().getMenuBar().setVisible(true);}
```

This way you just hide nested presenter or any other presenter or widget on desired page. You could do this, with removeFromParent() method but on user navigation event, your object will not be reinserted, because you removed your object form DOM of your page. It will eventually be inserted by calling onReveal() method if user reload the page. So if you want to just to "hide" some of your panels setVisible() is way to go, else if you want to permanetlly remove object removeFromParent() is your choice.